# how to extract python data frame from JSON string

Tags: python, json

I've got the following JSON string in a txt file and I'm trying to extract a data frame from the 'visualLogs' variable. I can read the JSON string in and I can access the visualLogs list, but I have failed all day long to convert this into a 9 column data frame of floating point numbers

```
{
  "visualScore" : 0,
  "selfReportingResults" : 5,
  "voiceScore" : "No Data",
  "selfReportScore" : 0,
  "subject" : "Baseline for patient: 108",
  "email" : "steven.vannoy@gmail.com",
  "visualLogs" : [
    "time,anger,contempt,disgust,engagement,joy,sadness,surprise,valence\r22.61086,0.00633,0.19347,0.56258,0.18005,0.00223,0.0165,0.31969,0.0\r22.81096,0.00478,0.19439,0.45847,0.09747,0.00188,0.02188,0.22043,0.0\r"
  ],
  "askedQuestions" : [
    "What is your name?",
    "How old are you?",
    "What tim is it?"
  ],
  "voiceCompleteResults" : {
    "status" : "fail"
  }
}

with open(f4lJasonFileName) as data_file:
    feelDat = json.load(data_file)

x = feelDat['visualLogs'][0] # Ultimately there will be more than one of these
```

All of my attempts to convert x to a data frame have failed. I've achieved getting a 1 column data frame of text values, but that's not what I need.

I've replaced those '\r' characters with commas, which ends up getting the one column text data frame, but I want 9 columns with the labels and then rows of floating points.

Comment: Do you want an actual `pandas` dataframe, or just a 2-dimensional list?

Comment: @Paul, well, I believe I want a data frame. R is my native language and I'm used to working with data in data frames. My current understanding is the pandas data frame and R data frame are very similar structures. I'll be doing some modeling on this data. I'm using python because of it's awesome support for web development as this data is coming in through an API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have loaded the json, you need to split on \r then on the commas:

```
import  pandas as pd

spl = d["visualLogs"][0].split("\r")


df = pd.DataFrame([v for v in map(lambda x: x.split(","), spl[1:]) if v[0]], columns=spl[0].split(","))
```

Probably easier to understand broken into parts:

```
import pandas as pd

# split into lines creating an iterator so we don't have to slice.
spl = iter(d["visualLogs"][0].rstrip().split("\r"))

# split first line to get the  column names.
columns = next(spl).split(",")

# split remaining lines into individual rows, removing empty row.
rows = [v for v in (sub_str.split(",") for sub_str in spl) if len(v) > 1]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=rows, columns=columns)
```

We could also just `spl = iter(d["visualLogs"][0].split())` as there is no other whitespace.

Or use *read_csv* using a *StringIO* object:

```
import pandas as pd
spl = d["visualLogs"][0]

from io import StringIO
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(spl))
```

Which gives you:

```
      time    anger  contempt  disgust  engagement      joy  sadness  \
0  22.61086  0.00633   0.19347  0.56258     0.18005  0.00223  0.01650   
1  22.81096  0.00478   0.19439  0.45847     0.09747  0.00188  0.02188   

   surprise  valence  
0   0.31969        0  
1   0.22043        0
```

Comment: Gah, edited your answer while I was writing up mine! `pandas` seems fine at understanding `\r` as a line separator, so no need to split and re-join.

Comment: @Paul, I tried without but just realised I had already split on the \r when I did, doh!

Comment: Also, you may want to mention that `StringIO` moved between 2.x and 3.x I think. If you use `from io import StringIO` you'll be compatible with both. `from six.moves import StringIO` probably handles other cases (not sure when `io` was backported).

Comment: @Paul, true, I  normally actually  use it, less typing :)

Comment: Thanks, I was close to getting the second method but didn't get it quite right. I don't understand the first method so much, but it does work and I will figure out how it does so as I get better with python. I wish I'd asked this question earlier in the day! But, I learned a lot :)

Comment: @svannoy, no worries, I added another way and a few comments so hopefully it makes it easier to understand.

Comment: The comments are very helpful,  thanks @PadraicCunningham. My appreciation for the 'iterator' has gone up tremendously. One question, the first version creates a DF where the items are of type 'object' whereas the second one creates a DF where the items are of type float64 (judging from the output of df.info(). If I run df.mean() on the second version I get expected results, but on the first version I just get a message "Series([], type: float64). I'm sure there's a way to convert the columns.

Comment: I'm sure this isn't the most efficient way to do the floats, but it works:   

    `rows = [v for v in (sub_str.split(",") for sub_str in spl) if len(v) > 1]
     rows[0]
     floatRows=[]
     for i in rows:
        floatRow = []
        for j  in i:
            floatRow.append(float(j))
        floatRows.append(floatRow)`